# Regex pattern for preg_replace_all to find urls without image extension

Tags: php, regex

I need pattern to find urls in xml file which not have png or jpg extension (between picture tags)

example:

```
$xml ="<Picture>http://page.com</Picture>
<Picture>http://page.pafghj</Picture>
<Picture>http://page.www.com/asdads.pdf</Picture>
<Title>asaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</Title>";


$pattern = '#<Picture>(?![^" ]*(?:jpg|png))[^" ]+#';
$matches = [];
preg_match_all($pattern, $xml, $matches);

echo '<pre>';print_r($matches);echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: build an "endswith" function, use XPath and register the function: http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.registerphpfunctions.php . Or use only DOMDocument and `getElementsByTagName` and filter the nodes in a foreach loop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$pattern = '#<Picture>(((?!(jpg|png)).)*)</Picture>#mU';
```

The ((?!(jpg|png)).)* is a negative look-around will remove any line with jpg or png. The mU flags will set multiline search.